# Top-bar animates on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to recreate the scrolling effect found on [here](https://embacy.io/): As you scroll, an orange bar begins to stretch across the top of the screen, and if you scroll back up to the top, it moves back in the other direction.

Would anyone be able to help get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a scroll indicator. You can follow this tutorial.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

You need the following html, css and js. This will add a progress bar the top which will show how much the page has been scrolled.

Code:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* The progress container (grey background) */

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
}


/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div> More content .. </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a progress bar made up from 2 div elements.
the inner div will represent the value of the scroll bar.
the value will be calculated via scroll event listener and will be reset to the DOM after every change of the scroll bar.

Here is my suggestion:

[LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=5bde0534-5171-4655-bf97-4711bdb708a0)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--remove comment to use jquery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div id="pb-value">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">    
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Quisque rutrum urna turpis, nec auctor massa scelerisque quis.
        Donec auctor erat eget ultrices luctus.
        Mauris varius, ...
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  margin:0;
}
.progress-bar
{
  position:fixed;
  display:inline-block;
  height:15px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:gray;
  z-index:999;
}
#pb-value
{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:0;
  background-color:orange;
  height:100%;
}
.content
{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
}
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollAnim);
function scrollAnim () {
  var val = getScrollPercent();
  document.getElementById('pb-value').style.width = val + "%";
}
function getScrollPercent()
{
  var maxvalue = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  var val = $(document).scrollTop()
  return (val / maxvalue)*100;
}
```